# Dexie - Check if a record exists and initialize it if not present

Tags: angular, dexie

I'm implementing Dexie 2.0 in an Angular2 project.

I have a simple table that should contain only one record use for order naming.

What I have to do is check in IndexedDb if the table has the record and if not, initialize it... Very simple.

This is the code:

```
this.OrderCounter.toArray().then(function (arr) {
        if (arr.length == 1) {
          console.log('Do nothing');
        }
        else {
          console.log('Initialize Counter');          
          this.OrderCounter.add(1);          
        }
      });
```

In this moment the table is empty and if I run the script I get "this is undefined" on the row command that initialize the record...

What do I have to change?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the nature of `this` in javascript that is the problem. Try replace `function (arr) { ... }` with an arrow function `(arr) => { ... }` and your `this` pointer will stick to your class instance.

Comment: Thanks David... You are precious like always...
Dexie component works really fine in my first project that implements local storage...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with an older version of JavaScript then you might not have access to arrow functions. An older way to fix this would be to toss "this" into a variable before the function call.

```
var self = this;
this.OrderCounter.toArray().then(function (arr) {
if (arr.length == 1) {
  console.log('Do nothing');
}
else {
  console.log('Initialize Counter');          
  self.OrderCounter.add(1);          
}
```

});